# Limited Profiles like in Facebook

Tags: sql, social-networking

I am trying to create a social networking app for my project. This requires that when a user A tries to access the profile of a non-friend user B, it has to display only limited information. And when the user A becomes the friend of B, or user B changes his privacy settings, then all his profile information should be visible.

This looks the same as facebook, but i am trying to understand how is this implemented in SQL/database.

Your replies will be most helpful..

Comment: You should add an example of what you have tried to this point.

Comment: I think this is as simple as writing a statement to check if they are friends and then responding with the appropriate content. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its  simple.Just  use  a  field  called  isfriend  among  two  persons and  by  default  for   any  person,  it  would  be  false  and  if  it  is  false  he  can't  see  the  info.  of  other  persons unless  and  until   other  becomes  friend  and  in  that  case  value  of  isfriend  for  the  two  persons  would  be  true  and  they  can  see  each  others  details.Did  i  missed  something?